# Pandas index names, axis labels, and levels

Tags: pandas

Python for Data Analysis (2e, 219) says:

[image]

But I am, unfortunately, confused. So:

- What are "index names"?
- What are "axis labels"?
- What are "axis levels"?
- Which category do "rows" and "columns" fall into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following DataFrame.

```
colidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('Yes', 'No'), ('Yes', 'No')],
                                    names=['Heart Disease', 'High Blood Pressure'])
rowidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('Female', 'Male'), ('Single', 'Married')], 
                                    names=['Sex', 'Marital Status'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 4), index=rowidx, columns=colidx))
```

```
Heart Disease          Yes     No   
High Blood Pressure    Yes No Yes No
Sex    Marital Status              
Female Single            5  0   3  3
       Married           7  9   3  5
Male   Single            2  4   7  6
       Married           8  8   1  6
```

This is basically a cross table broken down by four categories. In rows, it has `Sex` and `Marital Status` and in columns it has `Heart Disease` and `High Blood Pressure`.

It has four rows and four columns. The first row's label is `(Female, Single)`. Wes uses `axis label`  as the name of a specific row or a column in this book. For rows and columns pandas uses the same terminology as numpy and the rows become `axis=0` and columns become `axis=1`.

An axis may have different levels. In the sample DataFrame, rows, or 0th axis have two levels: `Sex`  and `Marital Status`. For `axis=1`, the levels are `Heart Disease`  and `High Blood Pressure`. You can also call them `index names` and `column names` respectively.