# persistent column label in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have an issue where trying to work with pandas' indexing, this first happened on a larger set and i was able to recreate it in this dummy dataframe. Apologies if my table formatting is terrible, I don't know how to make it better visually.

```
Unnamed: 0  col1 col2 col3

0   Name    Sun Mon Tue
1   one     1   2   1
2   two     4   4   3
3   three   2   1   1
4   four    1   5   5
5   five    1   5   5
6   six     5   1   1
7   seven   5   5   6
8   eight   5   3   4
9   nine    5   3   3
```

So what i am trying to do is to rename the 1st column label ('Unnamed: 0') to something meaningful, but then when i finally try to reset_index, the index "column" has the name "test" for some reason, while the first actual column gets the label "index".

```py
df.rename({df.columns[0]: 'test'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df.set_index('test', inplace=True)
dft = df.transpose()
dft

    test    Name    one two three four five six seven eight nine
    col1    Sun     1   4   2   1   1   5   5   5   5
    col2    Mon     2   4   1   5   5   1   5   3   3
    col3    Tue     1   3   1   5   5   1   6   4   3
```

First of all, if my understanding is correct, index is not even an actual column in the dataframe, why does it get to have a label when resetting index?

And more importantly, why are the labels "test" and "index" reversed?

```
dft.reset_index(inplace=True)
dft

test index  Name    one two three four five six seven eight nine
0   col1    Sun     1   4   2   1   1   5   5   5   5
1   col2    Mon     2   4   1   5   5   1   5   3   3
2   col3    Tue     1   3   1   5   5   1   6   4   3
```

I have tried every possible combination of set_index / reset_index i can think of, trying drop=True & inplace=True but i cannot find a way to create a proper index, like the one i started with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the axis (index and column axis) [can have names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45899612/14627505).
This is useful for [multi-indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html).

When you call [`.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), the index is extracted into a new column, which is named how your index was named (by default, 'index').

If you want, you can [reset and rename index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40914267/14627505) in one line:

```py
df.rename_axis('Name').reset_index()
```

##### Why is `'test'` printed not where I expect?

After your code, if you `print(dft.columns)`, you will see:

```
Index(['index', 'Name', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'], 
      dtype='object', 
      name='test')
```

There are 11 columns. The column axis is called `'test'` (see `name='test'` in the output above).

Also: `print(dft.columns.name)` prints `test`.

So what you actually see when you print your dataframe are the column names, to the left of which is the name of the column axis: `'test'`.

It is NOT how the **index** axis is named. You can check: `print(type(dft.index.name))` prints `<class 'NoneType'>`.

##### Now, why is column axis named 'test'?

Let's see how it got there step by step.

```
df.rename({df.columns[0]: 'test'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

First column is now named `'test'`.

```py
df.set_index('test', inplace=True)
```

First column has moved from being a column to being an index. The index name is `'test'`. The old index disappeared.

```py
dft = df.transpose()
```

The column axis is now named `'test'`. The index is now named however the **column** axis was named **before** transposing.

Comment: So if I understand what you re saying correctly, the name "test" is the name of my columns axis (axis 1) and therefore bound to be the left-most of this axis? Is there a way to keep the name "test" as the label of the first column after resetting index (the column containing col1, col2, col3)? Maybe it's the way that i renamed the column in the first place that's problematic?

Comment: @moux , Yes. Pass 'test' to `rename_axis`.